# Diagnosing Suspend/Wakeup problems in Xubuntu

Tags: linux, suspend, xubuntu

I had my old laptop (Xubuntu LTE 20.04, Kernel 5.something) configured to suspend when I close the lid, which worked fine. When I switched to a new laptop (Tuxedo Pulse 15 - Gen2, Ryzen 7 5700U with onboard graphics) I simply removed the SSD from the old one and put it in the new one. After some updates (mostly Kernel, now at 5.15.0.76) all worked fine and I could use the 2560x1440 resolution without problems.

Only the suspend-mechanism didn't work. That is: it somehow works, because the systems goes to sleep alright when I close the lid, but when I open it again and press the power button the lights on the keyboard come on and the system is definitely doing something, but the display remains black (that is: not "black background", but completely switched off).

Not knowing how to diagnose the problem (I work on UNIX, Linux is not my forte) I would like to get pointers how I could find out what goes wrong (and, hopefully, how to correct it). Are there any logs that I could check, traces I could take, configurations I could change, etc., etc..

Comment: I am no expert when it comes to laptops (the last time I used one was about 10 years ago) or suspend but some diagnostic questions come to mind: is it plugged in to a network? can you ping it? ssh to it and examine the logs (especially `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`)? in other words, is it just X or the GPU that isn't coming back properly from suspend, or is it the entire system?   Does it always do this on every suspend, or only sometimes? If sometimes, is there any pattern you can notice to the behaviour (e.g. only when running certain program, like playing a video)

Comment: @cas: actually this is exactly the answer I hoped to get. I will check these things and update my question. Thank you!.